# Is a ternary expression faster than Boolean logic?

Tags: java, performance, boolean

This doesn't look like a duplicate, as only one my solutions involves a branch.

Essentially, which of these two lines is more efficient? will be a java app, but it'd be nice to know a general answer well.

```
shouldRefresh = useCache ? refetchIfExpired : true;

shouldRefresh = !useCache || refetchIfExpired;
```

Comment: They should be identical.

Comment: Have you tried javap to disassemble the the resulting code? And then you could look at what the HotSpot compiler produces on several platforms. I would not believe any statements here that I had not made up myself :-)

Comment: Why does it matter? The question "Is this code easy to understand?" is so much more important than the particular efficiency of a single line that it's impossible to overstate.

Comment: **Please don't worry about "fastest" without having first done some sort of measurement that it matters.**
Rather than worrying about fastest, think about which way is clearest.

Comment: That doesn't look like a duplicate, as both solutions involve a branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JIT compiler will figure out the fastest operation and use that. Use whatever makes the most sense to read. Don't optimize prematurely.

For interest's sake: If this were being compiled without optimizations, then the boolean operator would be faster. It's a simple mathematical operation, which takes just one CPU cycle (plus another for the `!` operator), whereas the ternary expression would require a branch, which interrupts the pipeline if branch prediction guesses wrong.

Comment: That last part isn't true.  The conditional or (||) operator doesn't evaluate the second part if the first part is true.  The performance will be exactly the same.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: You're right. I don't know what I was thinking. :-P

Answer (score 1):

I would not care about performance here, but about **readability**. With this aspect, the ternary operator wins in your example. By the way, I expect roughly the same performance.

You can also look how readability helps to save time in maintenance of code. So what is more important? Almost unmeasurable micro-optimization or easier understanding? And when you think a comment shall fix this, so I consider this as an unnecessary writing effort which also costs time.

Comment: Readability is easily fixed by a comment, which doesn't affect performance

Comment: Why would you say that ternary wins at readability?

Comment: @LouisWasserman At least speaking for me, the evaluation of logical and boolean operators put slightly more mental stress upon me. If you are lucky with this style then fine for you ;-)

Comment: @Supuhstar: Then you're forcing someone to read and maintain both the code and the comments, and sometimes the comments don't match what the code does. Far better to write code that is easy to understand in the first place. In most cases, that will not have a noticeable detrimental effect on performance.